# Kendo Date Picker Selecting Date should start from years

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-datepicker

I am using kendo date picker for Date of birth option I need to select the date in the following orders (Range of 10 years should be displayed i.e (`1991-2000`))`years->month->day`. By default I can choose only by clicking the header tabs. It will change to `day->month->years`.

If it starts from year, picking up Date of birth will be easy.

Comment: Please add your detail code, it is difficult to answer your question without sufficient info.

Comment: @KhalidHussain : i have not started to implement i am speaking about the general date picker option check this demo from kendo. Default selection of this date pickers starts with date/day. Once we click on the header it get changes to month->year. I clearly mentioned about that it has to be selected from year->month->day/date.reverse manner of the default behaviour. check the default behaviour of kendo date picker over here
http://dojo.telerik.com/aTigE

Comment: @KhalidHussain: If you doesn't know the answer don't down vote.
If it is a duplicate question then show the duplicate question.
i have given enough explanation on this.

Comment: [Please read the doc first](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/datepicker). [Here is the demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/iZEXo) where I have changed the date format using this line of code `format: "yyyy/MM/dd"`. Kendo provides lot of options, you can customize it according to your requirement.

Comment: @KhalidHussain : Kindly read the question first i am not asking for the format i have mentioned about selection order. User has to first select the year and should select month and needs to select the day/date.

Comment: `i have not started to implement`, This type of question is `off-topic` on SO. this site provides solution for coding problem. May be you do not understand the purpose of this site. Please read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) first. Then modify your question.

Comment: You should provide what you have tried so far to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is not supported behavior, but if you do the following after the control is initialized, it will give you the desired functionality.

```
var cal = $('#Date').data('kendoDatePicker').dateView;
var nav = cal.div.find('.k-nav-fast');
nav.off('click.kendoCalendar');
nav.on('click', function() { cal.calendar.navigate(cal._current, 3) });
```

// if this works for you, please mark it as an answer =)

Comment: @Hariharan - Why do you continue to argue with Khalid when I posted the answer to your question 24 hours ago? If there is a problem with this answer, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish this, Kendo UI Date Picker provide below 2 attributes (options)

**data-start  or start** : This option will allow us to configure from where kendo date picker will start e.g. in your case it can be “decade”

Possible values are

"*month*" - Shows the days of the month.

"*year*" - Shows the months of the year.

"*decade*" - Shows the years of the decade.

"*century*" - Shows the decades from the century.

**data-depth or depth**: This option will allow us to configure the till where we need to go, e.g. in your case you need to go till “month” level so use "month"

Possible values are

"*month*" - Shows the days of the month.

"*year*" - Shows the months of the year.

"*decade*" - Shows the years of the decade.

"*century*" - Shows the decades from the century.